# cp command does not find files when called from a Scala Process

Tags: scala, sbt, cp

As part of an sbt build process, I am calling Linux cp from Scala to copy a directory structure with a code like:

```
Process("cp -R -f "/home/user/source/* " "/home/user/target").!
```

Under `/home/user/source` there are three directories which are not copied, but I get the message

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/user/source/*’: No such file or directory
```

Despite an `ls /home/user/source` from a command line does find the directories and moreover a

```
Process("rm -R -f "/home/user/source").!
```

does remove the directory.

Any suggestion on why cp is not working when called from Scala Process?

Below is the full code of my Build.scala:

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._
import sys.process.Process
import java.io.File

object myBuild extends Build {
    lazy val myVersion = "1.10.0"
    lazy val myJar = "myproj-" + myVersion + ".jar"

    lazy val webjarToExtract = TaskKey[Seq[File]]("webjar-to-extract", "JAR files to be extracted")

    lazy val extractJarTarget = SettingKey[File]("extract-jar-target", "Target directory for extracted JAR file")

    lazy val extractJar = TaskKey[Unit]("extract-webjar", "Extract WebJar file")

    lazy val mySettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
        webjarToExtract <<= (baseDirectory) map { dir => Seq(dir / "lib" / myJar) },

        // define the target directory
        extractJarTarget <<= (baseDirectory)(_ / "tmp"),

        // task to extract jar files
        extractJar <<= (webjarToExtract, extractJarTarget, streams) map { (jars, target, streams) =>
            jars foreach { jar =>
                streams.log.info("Extracting " + jar.getName + " to " + target)
                IO.unzip(jar, target)
            }
            val baseDir = new java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath
            Process("cp -R -f " + baseDir + "/tmp/META-INF/resources/webjars/thejars/" + myVersion + "/* " + baseDir + "/public").!
            Process("rm -R -f " + baseDir + "/tmp/META-INF").!
        },

        // make it run before compile
        compile in Compile <<= extractJar map { _ => sbt.inc.Analysis.Empty }
    )

    lazy val myproj: Project = Project("myproj", file(".")) settings (mySettings: _*)
}
```

Comment: You're expecting shell expansion to work. I'd assume there is a flag for that. I'd recommend using the sbt file API. http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.12/api/index.html#sbt.IO$

Answer (score 4):

As @Reactormonk has pointed out in the comments, to get shell expansion you need to invoke the shell.

```
scala> import scala.sys.process._
import scala.sys.process._

scala> Seq("cp", "JunkFrom/*", "JunkTo").!
cp: cannot stat 'JunkFrom/*': No such file or directory
res0: Int = 1

scala> Seq("sh", "-c", "cp JunkFrom/* JunkTo").!
res1: Int = 0
```